# use of osmdroid for a map base application

Tags: android, eclipse

i am trying to write a map base application via osmdroid and i want when the user opens the application, can see googlemaps online.
i write codes in Eclipse but i can't see google maps when i run my application on  my virtual device
this is my Androidmanifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />   
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.osm.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="myapikey" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

it is my codes:

```
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         MapView mapView=new MapView(this, 256);
  //         mapView mapView = new m(this, 256);


    mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapView.getController().setZoom(14);
        mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(34.638293,50.876312));

        setContentView(mapView);
        mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
}

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this:

```
private void setMapView() {

    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
    }


    final com.google.android.maps.MapView mapView = new com.google.android.maps.MapView(this, ManifestUtil.retrieveKey(this, "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"));
    setContentView(mapView);
    mMap = MapFactory.getMap(mapView);

    final Position position = new Position(52.370816, 9.735936); // Hannover
    position.setZoomLevel(14);
    mMap.setPosition(position);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);

    addMarkers();

    addPolyline();

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(final IPosition position) {
            Log.d(Constants.LOGTAG, "onCameraChange");
        }
    });
}
```

this is from osmdroid sample. As you can see you need google GEO API key to obtain google map tiles to your app. Maybe it would be better solution to use different maps then google maps. This is the official documentation which lists all "out of the box" map sources you can use https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Map-Sources